# linux. Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to solve Gaussian Elimination and Back Substitution in C.
But I've got Segmentation fault(Core dumped) error in shell.

this is the part of main code.

```c
float **a = (float **) malloc(sizeof(float*) *n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    a[i] = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float) *n);

float *b = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float) *n);
float *x = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float) *n);
```

```
Gaussian(n, &a, &b);
BackSubstitution(n, &a, &b, &x);
```

and below is gaussian.c . I think there is some problem with gaussian.c

```c
#include <math.h>

void Gaussian(int n, float ***arr, float **arr2)
{
    for (int l = 0; l < n - 1; l++)
    {
        for (int i = l + 1, j = 1; i < n && j < n; i++, j++)
        { (*arr)[i][j] = (*arr)[i][j] - ((*arr)[i][l] / (*arr)[l][l]) * (*arr)[l][j];
            (*arr2)[i] = (*arr2)[i] - ((*arr)[i][l] / (*arr)[l][l]) * (*arr2)[l];
        }
    }
}

void BackSubstitution(int n, float ***arr, float **arr2, float **result)
{
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        (*result)[i] = (*arr2)[i] / (*arr)[i][i];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        { (*arr2)[j] = (*arr2)[j] - (*result)[i] * (*arr)[j][i];
            (*arr)[j][i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong that generate segmentation fault?

Comment: Yes, a segmentation fault usually indicates that something is wrong. You can use a debugger to tell you where exactly the crash happened. You can increase the likelihood of getting a more useful answer by providing a [mre] instead of snippets of code that may or may not actually contain the buggy code.

Comment: whats `n` in your first line of code?

Comment: I think the reason you r getting a seg fault is bcoz u missed the `#include <stdio.h>` header. I added that and a random value to `n` and code successfully complies without any seg faults

Comment: @CrissHills - `stdio.h` has nothing to do with his crash.

Comment: @selbie, i understand but thats the only thing i modified and the code compiles

Comment: I see two possible bugs. For starters, all your floating point data isn't initialized.  Use `calloc` to zero-init all your data to avoid some weird floating point exception. Also, Your `b` array is never fully initialized like you did `a`.  And I don't understand why you allocate an array of float pointers instead of just an array of floats.

Comment: You could shave one star off the code. Unless you want to allocate a new array and point the caller's variable to that, there's no need to pass by pointer. So one layer of `&` and `*` indirections could be removed. It fixes nothing, but it may make it slightly more readable. Three-star pointers usually make people run away...

Comment: @CrissHills Compilation is not the problem; a segmentation fault is a runtime error.

Comment: I have found that in these for loops, removing calculations and just performing only the array access operations to be helpful in figuring out the culprit, otherwise @dratenik's suggestion is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

You have no reason to pass your arrays by pointer reference.  So your functions gets much easier by eliminating one extra reference:

```
void Gaussian(int n, float** arr, float* arr2) {
    for (int l = 0; l < n - 1; l++) {
        for (int i = l + 1, j = 1; i < n && j < n; i++, j++) {
            arr[i][j] = arr[i][j] - arr[i][l] / arr[l][l] * arr[l][j];
            arr2[i] = arr2[i] - arr[i][l] / arr[l][l] * arr2[l];
        }
    }
}

void BackSubstitution(int n, float** arr, float* arr2, float* result) {
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        result[i] = arr2[i] / arr[i][i];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            arr2[j] = arr2[j] - result[i] * arr[j][i];
            arr[j][i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Second, you aren't actually initializing the contents of your arrays with valid data.  Some of your array initializations are missing initializations to actual floating point data. Without this, your arrays have garbage data - which won't play well with floating point.

So aside from initializing your arrays correctly, you don't have to pass them in by pointer (because arrays degrade to pointers in function calls)

```
int n = 10;

float** a = (float**)malloc(n * sizeof(float*));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    a[i] = (float*)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = 0.0f;  // you initialize a[i][j] with your data
    }
}

float* b = (float*)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
float* x = (float*)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    b[i] = 0.0f;
    x[i] = 0.0f;
}

Gaussian(n, a, b);
BackSubstitution(n, a, b, x);
```